# Same request, different response between Postman and Axios (node)

Tags: node.js, axios, postman

I'm sending a post request with Postman, and I am able to login. Using the same header and data, I get a different response with axios in node.

I compared the request using Fiddler:
data Postman:

```
_csrf=8806aed7-f222-417f-a3aa-a0e3c0876075&loginMail=my.email%40email.com&loginWenkseSessionId=a419116a-0349-4da3-b78f-0012d5964bfb&password=mypassword&fingerprint=3746b536f50ec270a12a7a4e74f3e4a1
```

data axios:

```
_csrf=8806aed7-f222-417f-a3aa-a0e3c0876075&loginMail=my.email%40email.com&loginWenkseSessionId=a419116a-0349-4da3-b78f-0012d5964bfb&password=mypassword&fingerprint=3746b536f50ec270a12a7a4e74f3e4a1
```

header postman:

```
POST https://www.my-url.com/page.html?targetUrl=/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.my-url.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.my-url.com/
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=345619E4B9164E346E099B23C2EA1762-mc5.koeb46-5_i01_1001; rbzid=DcpM4PC9zel6z+f6GAv5kAymylqw001/v299Eg/jfmAzp/jIzSZxjje6++LdfAPK5HlgwAtqDhYScjobif3t21F4I0MqlMIWC7WE61suzUrkmWGJiRvZE2iVsxOZTdeCYI8kt9yAltmgj5v+lz2+SY1rmnKSkCEiV/VfMZ5aaDZT/1WnWRZ/7HXIM5yRd+uzcG4SpJylPSwrNlEF4Z03GURur6nao2uLMV727hBs0GH5dW4run3KoQGS+GbTV4zBifAKIkqyhKoDlVP70w13z3jg5HOdDihROWDG0hROP4jVzbY92gYYQp11AkPhVJtn; rbzsessionid=aa17403285c68f873066a34ca3967ddf;
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Postman-Token: 5851992c-e383-4369-9bf5-93ec71e466e6
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 216
```

header axios

```
POST https://www.my-url.com/page.html?targetUrl=/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
host: www.my-url.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept-Language: fr,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.my-url.com/
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=345619E4B9164E346E099B23C2EA1762-mc5.koeb46-5_i01_1001; rbzid=DcpM4PC9zel6z+f6GAv5kAymylqw001/v299Eg/jfmAzp/jIzSZxjje6++LdfAPK5HlgwAtqDhYScjobif3t21F4I0MqlMIWC7WE61suzUrkmWGJiRvZE2iVsxOZTdeCYI8kt9yAltmgj5v+lz2+SY1rmnKSkCEiV/VfMZ5aaDZT/1WnWRZ/7HXIM5yRd+uzcG4SpJylPSwrNlEF4Z03GURur6nao2uLMV727hBs0GH5dW4run3KoQGS+GbTV4zBifAKIkqyhKoDlVP70w13z3jg5HOdDihROWDG0hROP4jVzbY92gYYQp11AkPhVJtn; rbzsessionid=aa17403285c68f873066a34ca3967ddf;
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Length: 216
```

The data are strictly identical.
The headers have 2 differences:
 - the "Host" from postman has an uppercase, axios has a lowercase "h".. although my code has it uppercase, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ (see bellow)
 - Postman has an additional Postman-Token.

My axios code:

```
const postData = qs.stringify({
    "_csrf": "8806aed7-f222-417f-a3aa-a0e3c0876075",
    "loginMail": "my.email@email.com",
    "loginWenkseSessionId": "a419116a-0349-4da3-b78f-0012d5964bfb",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "fingerprint": "3746b536f50ec270a12a7a4e74f3e4a1"
  });

const resp = await axios.post(
    loginUrl,
    postData,
    {
        headers: 
        {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0",
            "Host": "www.my-url.com",
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Language": "fr,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.3",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Referer": "https://www.my-url.com/",
            "DNT": "1",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Cookie": "JSESSIONID=345619E4B9164E346E099B23C2EA1762-mc5.koeb46-5_i01_1001; rbzid=DcpM4PC9zel6z+f6GAv5kAymylqw001/v299Eg/jfmAzp/jIzSZxjje6++LdfAPK5HlgwAtqDhYScjobif3t21F4I0MqlMIWC7WE61suzUrkmWGJiRvZE2iVsxOZTdeCYI8kt9yAltmgj5v+lz2+SY1rmnKSkCEiV/VfMZ5aaDZT/1WnWRZ/7HXIM5yRd+uzcG4SpJylPSwrNlEF4Z03GURur6nao2uLMV727hBs0GH5dW4run3KoQGS+GbTV4zBifAKIkqyhKoDlVP70w13z3jg5HOdDihROWDG0hROP4jVzbY92gYYQp11AkPhVJtn; rbzsessionid=aa17403285c68f873066a34ca3967ddf;",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
            "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        }
    }
);
```

Edit: Answers from the server:

Axios headers and answer:

```
status: 200,
statusText: 'OK',
headers: {
  server: 'rhino-core-shield',
  date: 'Sat, 28 Mar 2020 13:25:04 GMT',
  'content-type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
  requires_auth: '1',
  'set-cookie': [
    'JSESSIONID=9364C40A071C826484EC0D96EA2F83AA-mc5.koeb47-31_i01_1001; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly',
    'up=%7B%22ln%22%3A%25548484226%11%7D; Expires=Thu, 24-Sep-2020 13:25:04 GMT; Path=/; Secure',
    'GCLB=AB2LnqCH0fobagE; path=/; HttpOnly'
  ],
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  expires: '0',
  'content-language': 'de-DE',
  vary: 'Origin, Accept-Encoding',
  'x-varnish': '484155822',
  age: '0',
  'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
  via: '1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0), 1.1 google',
  'alt-svc': 'clear',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
},
config: {
  url: 'https://www.my-url.com/my-page.html?targetUrl=/',
  method: 'post',
  data: 'loginMail=my-email%40email.com&_csrf=236a81db-6d63-438f-9b68-e3a76403c61e&password=my-password&fingerprint=3746b536f50ec270a12a7a4e74f3e4a1',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    Referer: 'https://www.my-url.com/',
    DNT: '1',
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    Cookie: 'JSESSIONID=345619E4B9164E346E099B23C2EA1762-mc5.koeb46-5_i01_1001; rbzid=DcpM4PC9zel6z+f6GAv5kAymylqw001/v299Eg/jfmAzp/jIzSZxjje6++LdfAPK5HlgwAtqDhYScjobif3t21F4I0MqlMIWC7WE61suzUrkmWGJiRvZE2iVsxOZTdeCYI8kt9yAltmgj5v+lz2+SY1rmnKSkCEiV/VfMZ5aaDZT/1WnWRZ/7HXIM5yRd+uzcG4SpJylPSwrNlEF4Z03GURur6nao2uLMV727hBs0GH5dW4run3KoQGS+GbTV4zBifAKIkqyhKoDlVP70w13z3jg5HOdDihROWDG0hROP4jVzbY92gYYQp11AkPhVJtn; rbzsessionid=aa17403285c68f873066a34ca3967ddf; '
  },
  transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
  transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
  timeout: 0,
  adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
  xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
  maxContentLength: -1,
  validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
},
request: ClientRequest {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    socket: [Function],
    abort: [Function],
    aborted: [Function],
    error: [Function],
    timeout: [Function],
    prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
  },
  _eventsCount: 6,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  _last: true,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  _contentLength: 0,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  socket: TLSSocket {
    _tlsOptions: [Object],
    _secureEstablished: true,
    _securePending: false,
    _newSessionPending: false,
    _controlReleased: true,
    _SNICallback: null,
    servername: false,
    alpnProtocol: false,
    authorized: true,
    authorizationError: null,
    encrypted: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype],
    _eventsCount: 8,
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: 'www.my-url.com',
    _readableState: [ReadableState],
    readable: false,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: [WritableState],
    writable: false,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: undefined,
    _server: null,
    ssl: null,
    _requestCert: true,
    _rejectUnauthorized: true,
    parser: null,
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    [Symbol(res)]: null,
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 30,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 7787,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 955,
    [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
  },
  connection: TLSSocket {
    _tlsOptions: [Object],
    _secureEstablished: true,
    _securePending: false,
    _newSessionPending: false,
    _controlReleased: true,
    _SNICallback: null,
    servername: false,
    alpnProtocol: false,
    authorized: true,
    authorizationError: null,
    encrypted: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype],
    _eventsCount: 8,
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: 'www.my-url.com',
    _readableState: [ReadableState],
    readable: false,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: [WritableState],
    writable: false,
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: undefined,
    _server: null,
    ssl: null,
    _requestCert: true,
    _rejectUnauthorized: true,
    parser: null,
    _httpMessage: [Circular],
    [Symbol(res)]: null,
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 30,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 7787,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 955,
    [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
  },
  _header: 'GET /my-page.html?targetUrl=/m-another-page.html&sessionExpired=true HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n' +
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0\r\n' +
    'Accept-Language: fr,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.3\r\n' +
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n' +
    'Referer: https://www.my-url.com/\r\n' +
    'DNT: 1\r\n' +
    'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n' +
    'Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n' +
    'Cookie: JSESSIONID=345619E4B9164E346E099B23C2EA1762-mc5.koeb46-5_i01_1001; rbzid=DcpM4PC9zel6z+f6GAv5kAymylqw001/v299Eg/jfmAzp/jIzSZxjje6++LdfAPK5HlgwAtqDhYScjobif3t21F4I0MqlMIWC7WE61suzUrkmWGJiRvZE2iVsxOZTdeCYI8kt9yAltmgj5v+lz2+SY1rmnKSkCEiV/VfMZ5aaDZT/1WnWRZ/7HXIM5yRd+uzcG4SpJylPSwrNlEF4Z03GURur6nao2uLMV727hBs0GH5dW4run3KoQGS+GbTV4zBifAKIkqyhKoDlVP70w13z3jg5HOdDihROWDG0hROP4jVzbY92gYYQp11AkPhVJtn; rbzsessionid=aa17403285c68f873066a34ca3967ddf; \r\n' +
    'Host: www.my-url.com\r\n' +
    '\r\n',
  _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
  agent: Agent {
    _events: [Object: null prototype],
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    defaultPort: 443,
    protocol: 'https:',
    options: [Object],
    requests: {},
    sockets: {},
    freeSockets: {},
    keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
    keepAlive: false,
    maxSockets: Infinity,
    maxFreeSockets: 256,
    maxCachedSessions: 100,
    _sessionCache: [Object]
  },
  socketPath: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/my-page.html?targetUrl=/m-another-page.html&sessionExpired=true',
  _ended: true,
  res: IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: [ReadableState],
    readable: false,
    _events: [Object: null prototype],
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: [TLSSocket],
    connection: [TLSSocket],
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: true,
    headers: [Object],
    rawHeaders: [Array],
    trailers: {},
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '',
    method: null,
    statusCode: 200,
    statusMessage: 'OK',
    client: [TLSSocket],
    _consuming: true,
    _dumped: false,
    req: [Circular],
    responseUrl: 'https://www.my-url.com/my-page.html?targetUrl=/m-another-page.html&sessionExpired=true',
    redirects: []
  },
  aborted: false,
  timeoutCb: null,
  upgradeOrConnect: false,
  parser: null,
  maxHeadersCount: null,
  _redirectable: Writable {
    _writableState: [WritableState],
    writable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype],
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: [Object],
    _redirectCount: 2,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 158,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function],
    _currentRequest: [Circular],
    _currentUrl: 'https://www.my-url.com/my-page.html?targetUrl=/m-another-page.html&sessionExpired=true',
    _isRedirect: true
  },
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    accept: [Array],
    'user-agent': [Array],
    'accept-language': [Array],
    'accept-encoding': [Array],
    referer: [Array],
    dnt: [Array],
    connection: [Array],
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': [Array],
    'cache-control': [Array],
    cookie: [Array],
    host: [Array]
  }
},
data: <"html of a page telling me my session is over">
```

Postman header answer:

POST https://www.my-url/m-my-page.html?targetUrl=/
It's a 302
GET https://www.my-url/m-another-page.html

```
GET /m-my-page.html?targetUrl=/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.my-url
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.my-url/m-my-page.html?targetUrl=/
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=345619E4B9164E346E099B23C2EA1762-mc5.koeb46-5_i01_1001; rbzid=DcpM4PC9zel6z+f6GAv5kAymylqw001/v299Eg/jfmAzp/jIzSZxjje6++LdfAPK5HlgwAtqDhYScjobif3t21F4I0MqlMIWC7WE61suzUrkmWGJiRvZE2iVsxOZTdeCYI8kt9yAltmgj5v+lz2+SY1rmnKSkCEiV/VfMZ5aaDZT/1WnWRZ/7HXIM5yRd+uzcG4SpJylPSwrNlEF4Z03GURur6nao2uLMV727hBs0GH5dW4run3KoQGS+GbTV4zBifAKIkqyhKoDlVP70w13z3jg5HOdDihROWDG0hROP4jVzbY92gYYQp11AkPhVJtn; rbzsessionid=aa17403285c68f873066a34ca3967ddf;; up=%7B%22ln%22%3A%22333539628%22%7D; wl=%7B%22l%22%3A%22%22%7D; GCLB=COiZgvKeiYvIhQE; JSESSIONID=9DC4DFDABFF9EB02F8666D8D9503CB8E-mc5.koeb47-12_i01_1001
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Postman-Token: 37d36a4b-f4a1-4493-94c5-719298b764ee
loginMail=my-email%40email.com&_csrf=236a81db-6d63-438f-9b68-e3a76403c61e&password=my-password&fingerprint=3746b536f50ec270a12a7a4e74f3e4a1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: rhino-core-shield
Date: Sat, 28 Mar 2020 13:48:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Content-Language: de-DE
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
X-Varnish: 484102076
Age: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0), 1.1 google
Alt-Svc: clear
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Postman response data is a HTML when I'm logged in.

I've tried using different Node server code generated by Postman, without luck.
Note that the same postman request can be sent several times, successfully. CSRF field isn't unique for a request.

What could I forget?

Comment: What problems are you encountering, specifically? HTTP headers are case-insensitive, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: could you add both responses so we can see the issue?!

Comment: The problem I encounter is that I'm successfully logged-in in `my-url.com` with postman, but not with axios.

I just edited my answer to add the answers from the server.

I just realized that postman is sending more cookies that just the one that I gave. It seems to add cookies from my browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this

```
const postData = qs.stringify({
            "_csrf": "8806aed7-f222-417f-a3aa-a0e3c0876075",
            "loginMail": "my.email@email.com",
            "loginWenkseSessionId": "a419116a-0349-4da3-b78f-0012d5964bfb",
            "password": "mypassword",
            "fingerprint": "3746b536f50ec270a12a7a4e74f3e4a1"
      });

     const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:   {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0",
                "Host": "www.my-url.com",
                "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
                "Accept-Language": "fr,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.3",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "Referer": "https://www.my-url.com/",
                "DNT": "1",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "Cookie": "JSESSIONID=345619E4B9164E346E099B23C2EA1762-mc5.koeb46-5_i01_1001; rbzid=DcpM4PC9zel6z+f6GAv5kAymylqw001/v299Eg/jfmAzp/jIzSZxjje6++LdfAPK5HlgwAtqDhYScjobif3t21F4I0MqlMIWC7WE61suzUrkmWGJiRvZE2iVsxOZTdeCYI8kt9yAltmgj5v+lz2+SY1rmnKSkCEiV/VfMZ5aaDZT/1WnWRZ/7HXIM5yRd+uzcG4SpJylPSwrNlEF4Z03GURur6nao2uLMV727hBs0GH5dW4run3KoQGS+GbTV4zBifAKIkqyhKoDlVP70w13z3jg5HOdDihROWDG0hROP4jVzbY92gYYQp11AkPhVJtn; rbzsessionid=aa17403285c68f873066a34ca3967ddf;",
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
                "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              },
            data: postData,
            loginUrl,
          };
          axios(options)
          .then(function (response) {
            //response
           })
```

Comment: I did try this before, `axios.post` and `axios({method: "POST"..` have the exact same behavior. Also your suggestion is wrong because `loginUrl` isn't a valid field, it should be `"url": loginUrl`. Please edit in case someone copy/paste it.

Comment: i saw this format in here https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Comment: please comment after seeing that...if wrong ill delete the answer

Comment: Again, this is just another way of doing the same, and the result is the same. I had read axios doc carefully, I'm already using `qs.stringify` as expected, the data from my request looks fine afaics.